# React Router won't change page after authentication, only if i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I'm working on a project that uses react router v6, and I'm trying to redirect the user to the home page, after he logs in, the problem is that when I try to log in, the token is generated without any problems, and the URL changes to "/home", but the page remains the same, it only change if i refresh the page, i "solved" it by using the navigate to change the URL, and navigate(0) to refresh the page, it works just fine but i feel like it's not the proper way to do it, if anyone is willing to explain how to do it in the proper way I would be grateful, this is the functions I'm using in the login page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button, Typography, Box, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useNavigate, Link, useLocation, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const data = {
      username,
      password,
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3001/auth/login",
        data
      );
      localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
      navigate("/home");
      navigate(0)

      if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("token"));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erro ao realizar login:", error);
    }

  };
```

And this is how i setup the react router, I don't really know if this is how it should be implemented, but i followed the tutorial on the documentation:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
  BrowserRouter,
  Outlet,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./index.css";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage";

const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token") != null;

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={authToken ? <HomePage /> : <LoginPage />} errorElement={<NotFound />} exact>
      <Route path="home/" element={authToken ? <HomePage /> : <LoginPage />}/>
      <Route path="auth/login/" element={authToken ? <HomePage /> : <LoginPage />}/>
      <Route path="auth/register/" element={authToken ? <HomePage /> : <RegisterPage />}/>
    </Route>
  )
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
    </RouterProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that localStorage is read only once when the app mounts, the `authToken` value won't ever change until you forcefully reload the page, e.g. remount the entire app.

Create a component that can read the `authToken` value when routes are accessed.

- Create a "private routes" component to check the auth token and render an `Outlet` for nested routes or a redirect to log in if not authenticated.
- Create an "anonymous routes" component to do the inverse to protect the login/registration routes.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token") != null;

  return authToken 
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/auth/login" replace />;
}

const AnonymousRoutes = () => {
  const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token") != null;

  return authToken 
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
}
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
        <Route
          path="home"
          element={<HomePage />}
          errorElement={<NotFound />}
        />
      </Route>
      <Route path="auth" element={<AnonymousRoutes />}>
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
      </Route>
    </>
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, just had to ajust some things in the formControl, because it was changing the page by default, but after I added the preventDefault function it worked as it should.